# Changing length of spring

Tags: forces, acceleration, spring, length

In this formula:

$$F_s = kx$$

what is the force that influences on the length of the spring?

For example I figured out if we pull up a mass attached to a spring with a force, the force of gravity will not be effective.

Comment: Of course the gravity will not be effective since the external force applied cancels it out.

Answer (score 0):

> In this formula "Fs = kx" what is the force that influences on the length of the spring?

It’s called a [restoring force](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restoring_force) which is any force such that it works to return an object back to its equilibrium position (there should be a negative sign in on the left ie.,

$$\vec F = - k \vec x$$

to signify that the force operates in a direction opposite to the displacement $\vec x$).

> For example I figured out if we pull up a mass attached to a spring with a force , the force of gravity will not be effective.

It depends. If the spring is lying horizontally (for example on a level table), then gravity will not stretch the spring. But if the spring/mass system is vertical, then gravity will do work stretching the spring toward the ground.